# Android Google Map zoom-in/out

Tags: android, google-maps

When I zoom in/out on Google Map, is there a way to make sure the map does not move (ie. only zoom in/out but the map center does not change)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOnCameraChangeListener`. When you stop zooming, you reset the center of the map

```
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cp) {
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point,cp.zoom));

            }});
```

Try it to disable the scrolling : `map.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);`
This should disable scrolling without disturb the zooming

Comment: Thanks, however this is only triggers when i stop zooming, anyway to make the map not move at all While zooming?

Comment: Edited my answer! Jope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line, You should expected what you want.

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```